# How to upgrade python in ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade, python

I'm using python Please take a look at this [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98z5W.png). But it is old version. So, I've downloaded a new version of source code for Python. But it's giving an error while compilation. Please help me out, How to upgrade my python version? I tried everything but none of them  are working out!

HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!

Comment: Don't provide output as an image, that's nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you downloaded it and are trying to compile from source.  Here's a link to a stackoverflow question I think might work for you - someone with the same issue.  Essentially you need to install openssl before compiling python from source.

[Compiling Python 3.4 is not copying pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592686/compiling-python-3-4-is-not-copying-pip)